# Custom Button Action launch in Browser and display blank screen in SF1

Tags: salesforce1-app, action

On an Account Object we had created a custom action called 'New Opportunity'.In this action we had defined certain fields and defined predefined values in those field.This was working earlier in Sf1.

Now when I navigate Account Record in Sf1 and in related list of account I click on 'New Opportunity' which is our custom action,as soon as I click on it instead of showing it in Sf1,it launches in mobile browser and display blanks screen.
I have checked the page layout & Custom action is added in related list of Account.

Has anyone faced this issued before?

What has changed recently in Salesforce?

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F0000000BRZWIA4

Let me know if that helps.

Comment: I have already refer this link earlier.Its not a quick Action I am talking about.If you goto 'Buttons, Links, and Actions' of any object there is button 'New Action'.We have some exiting custom action that was created and worked earlier in Sf1 but now suddenly it launches in browser instead of SF1 and display blank screen.